# Eclipse: Expression view not showing all although enough space

Tags: eclipse

please see this image:
[image]

As you can see when I'm using the 'expression' view, my left column has plenty of space. But regardless the expressions are shortened anyway. Mostly this is not that bad, but it annoys me... Especially if watching several similar expressions like I did in this example.

I guess it's a bug within the IDE?